# Get Rails to hit controller with an input tag submit

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

View:

```
%input{type: 'submit', action: 'home#create_user'}
```

Controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render 'home/index'
  end

  def sign_up
    render 'home/sign_up'
  end

  def create_user
    render 'dashboard/dashboard'
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
post 'home/create_user' => 'home#create_user', :as => :create_user
```

Why is this button not hitting the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By itself, an submit tag isn't going to generate the form.  I tried your code above and the button doesn't do anything.  Unless I'm forgetting INPUT doesn't have an ACTION attribute.

If you had a link to that page, the reason it's not working is because by default that link will be a GET request and you've restricted the route to POST.

So, either wrap it up in a form or use button_to or the :method => :post solutions to make it POST the request and it should work.

Something like this:

```
= button_to 'click me', create_user_path
= link_to 'click me', create_user_path, method: 'post'
```

Comment: You mean like this? %input{type: 'submit', action: 'home#create_user', method: 'post'}

Comment: This should be so easy. I am just trying to click a button and get the params sent to the controller and have the params set from a textbox. Is there something fundamental that I am missing here? I can do this with a form tag but I dont want to.